# UITableview scrolling to top after popViewControllerAnimated is called

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am having an issue with an `UITableView`.

I am displaying a collection of tracking records. After the user taps on a cell, a detail view controller is displayed with detailed data. My problem is after I call `popViewControllerAnimated:YES` from the Detail view controller, my table view is reseted and scrolls to the top position automatically.

I am not calling `[myTable reloadData];` on `viewWillAppear` and I find this behavior kinda strange.

Does anyone have an idea what I might be missing here?

Any help or tip would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Granit

Comment: try presenting the Detail ViewController instead of pushing.

Comment: [There's an iOS 8 issue with self-sizing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26602948/4151918) that causes the tableView to "jump." The more inaccurate the estimated height, the more pronounced the effect.  Using a better estimate will minimize the issue.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. Could you answer so I can accept your solution? @PetahChristian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known issue.

The more the `estimatedRowHeight` differs from the actual height, the more the table will jump when the push segue happens.  The easiest workaround is to use a much better estimate.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't call reloadData then either you re-add the table somewhere or you popped ViewController was reloaded because of some reason. Does ViewDidLoad called when you pop back?

How about storing the table scrolling state? (contentOffset)

Comment: Hi @Jaro i tried to scroll back to the stored scrolling state, but the table still is scrolling to top.

Comment: You have not just stored it but also restored it in viewWillAppear using [mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointSomething animated:YES];
?
One more thing: I hope u are not calling [table setContentSize:..] somewhere after presenting table cuzz that will do the same effect.

Comment: Seems that the issue with self-sizing caused the jump in the table view. Thanks for your comments :)